Отсутствует явный тип, требуется int C++
Всем привет, недавно я начал изучать C++ по книге Липмана "C++ для начинающих". На данном этапе, автор программирует свой массив, который является расширенной версией стандартного массива в C++.
Итак, в чём же состоит проблема. У нас есть класс IntArrayRC, который наследуется от класса IntArray. При определении функции virtual int& operator[] (int) const проблем не возникает, однако при написании его реализации, появляется ошибка Отсутствует явный тип, требуется int C++. Я попробовал поставить тип функции int, как и указано при определении, однако появилась новая ошибка: объявление несовместимо с "int &IntArrayRC::operator const".
IntArray.h:
class IntArray
{
public:
    explicit IntArray(int sz = DefaultArraySize);
    IntArray(int* array, int array_size);
    IntArray(const IntArray& rhs);

    const int size() { return _size; }
    
    bool operator == (const IntArray&) const;
    bool operator != (const IntArray&) const;

    IntArray& operator = (const IntArray&);
    int size() const { return _size; };

    virtual int& operator[] (int index) { return ia[index]; }
    virtual void sort();

    virtual int min() const;
    virtual int max() const;
    virtual int find(int value) const;
    virtual ~IntArray() { delete[] ia; }

protected:
    void init(int sz, int* array);
    int _size;
    int* ia;
    static const int DefaultArraySize = 12;
};

IntArrayRC.h:
#ifndef IntArrayRC_H
#define IntArrayRC_H

#include "IntArray.h"
#include <cassert>

class IntArrayRC : public IntArray
{
public:
    IntArrayRC(int sz = DefaultArraySize);
    IntArrayRC(const int* array, int array_size);
    IntArrayRC(const IntArrayRC& rhs);

    virtual int& operator[] (int) const;

private:
    void check_range(int ix);
};
#endif

IntArrayRC::operator[](int index)
{
    check_range(index);
    return ia[index];
};

inline void IntArrayRC::check_range(int index) {
    assert(index >= 0 && index < _size);
};

Данный фрагмент вы можете найти на странице 59 - 60, перейдя по ссылке: http://www.insycom.ru/html/metodmat/inf/Lipman.pdf

virtual int & operator[] (int) const; -> int & operator [] (int) override; квалификатор const делает из функции другую перегрузку. В определении пропущен тип возвращаемого значения.

Здравствуйте, спасибо, что уделили мне своё время, но ,к сожалению, ошибка не ушла(

IntArrayRC::operator[](int index) -> int& IntArrayRC::operator[](int index) const.
